# Ошибка в try: except:

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-translate, pyowm

```
import telebot
import pyowm
from googletrans import Translator

bot_token = '<в реальном проекте у меня здесь мой апи ключ бота>'
weather_token = '<здесь тоже>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
owm = pyowm.OWM(weather_token, language='ru')
translator = Translator(service_urls=[
    'translate.google.com'
])


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def weather_bot(message):
    town = translator.translate(message.text, dest='en')
    try:
        observation = owm.weather_at_place(town.text)
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нету такого города(села) "' + town.text + '"')
    w = observation.get_weather()
    temp = str(int(w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']))
    humidity = str(w.get_humidity())
    wind = None
    if int(w.get_wind()['deg']) == 0:
        wind = 'северный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) == 90:
        wind = 'восточный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + 'м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) == 180:
        wind = 'южный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) == 270:
        wind = 'западный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) >= 0 & int(w.get_wind()['deg']) <= 90:
        wind = 'северо-восточный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) >= 90 & int(w.get_wind()['deg']) <= 180:
        wind = 'юго-восточный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) >= 180 & int(w.get_wind()['deg']) <= 270:
        wind = 'юго-западный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'
    elif int(w.get_wind()['deg']) >= 270 & int(w.get_wind()['deg']) <= 360:
        wind = 'северо-западный, ' + str(int(w.get_wind()['speed'])) + ' м\с'

    answer = 'Сейчас в "' + message.text + '" ' + w.get_detailed_status() + ' \n'
    answer += 'Температура: ' + temp + '°С \n'
    answer += 'Влажность: ' + humidity + '% ртутного столба \n'
    answer += 'Ветер ' + wind

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=answer)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Воть..')

bot.polling()
```

Openweathermap содержит информацию о погоде не во всех городах, из-за этого возникла ошибка которая постоянно отправляет мне сообщение из блока `try:    except:`. По идее это сообщение должно появляться только один раз. Как это исправить? (У меня бот с вебхуком на спец площадке pythonanywhere и это код простого бота чтобы было понятнее т.к. ошибка проявляется в обоих случаях) Ссылка на бота: [Бот](http://t.me/my_first_weather_bot)

Comment: Исправь заголовок. В блоке try-except ошибок нет.

Comment: Насколько постоянно? Текст возникающего исключения внутри except читали?